# Is there a hook that fires after an ajax call?

Tags: ajax, hooks

I'm looking for a hook that is fired before the Ajax content is returned.

The reason is that I want to extend the cookies with the Secure attribute I need. Unfortunately is the plugin (woocommerce) not doing this by default so I need to add this manually.

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/

Comment: Maybe `wp_ajax_addItemAJAX` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_addItemAJAX`. (From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722444/9416618).)

Comment: I don't think you can filter setting a cookie like that. WordPress itself calls PHP's setcookie directly; WooCommerce has wc_setcookie but again there's no filter for the secure flag (except on the session cookie). You'll have to look at the specific AJAX code you're interested in and probably edit it.